# Python: character "\u200b" not recognized after freezing with py2app

Tags: python-3.x, py2app

We work with Sharepoint at my job, and sometimes the character ["\u200b"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), a zero-width character,  gets into our filenames and documents after copying something from Sharepoint.

I made an app with Python 3 and PyQt5 that monitors the clipboard, shows its contents using `repr()`, and displays a system notification if that character is found in the clipboard contents.

It works fine under Windows, works fine under El Capitan before freezing, but after freezing with py2app, my program shows "?" instead of "\u200b", and so the notification is not shown.  I'm testing in a virtual machine (VirtualBox), if that changes anything.

Is there any way to fix this with py2app, should I be using another freezing program, or should I change my code?

EDIT: I have a text file written in Japanese and I just noticed the same thing happens: before freezing, the Japanese characters are displayed correctly in my app, but after freezing they get converted to "?".

Thread that monitors the clipboard:

```
recent_value = ""
while True:
    tmp_value = pyperclip.paste()
    if tmp_value != recent_value:
        recent_value = tmp_value
        self.clip.emit(recent_value)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Validation in the app:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def clipboard_slot(self, value):
    real_value = repr(value)[1:][:-1]

    # validation
    if "\\u200b" in real_value:
        self.tray_icon.showMessage("Warning", "Invalid character detected in clipboard contents.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use unicode string.

"\u200b" must be u"\u200b"

```
 if u"\\u200b" in real_value:
            self.tray_icon.showMessage("Warning", "Invalid character detected in clipboard contents.")
```